# Matlab - Creating a generic matching template for pattern detection with the available set of images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision

I have a set of 5-10 images of a pattern. My task is to do the template matching to detect this pattern in the source image. But the template which needs to compared should be a generic one.The template  matching is working perfectly with all the given images on the auto correlation algorithm based on SSD.

My question is using the available template how do i create(design) a generic template.

The available templates are :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fTeeazmL-FWUFOY2NQT0d1eHc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My cumbersome way is to match the source image against each of the patterns, and do some logic on the matching results (union, cross, etc.)

Comment: @Yvon is correct.  If you're going to do template matching, you're going to have to compare your image with all of the templates in your database.  One way to completely avoid this is to use keypoint / feature based approaches.  That way, you compute a set of robust and **repeatable** features that you look for in the search images.  Things like SIFT, SURF, HOG, etc. work.

Comment: You might find [Detecting and Sketching the Common (CVPR 2010)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SketchTheCommon) helpful: given very few input images it outputs a common template. A related work for finding templates in images based on shape is [Matching Local Self-Similarities across Images and Videos (CVPR 2007)](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SelfSimilarities.html).

Comment: As your templates do look quite different, I'd go with Yvon's suggestion. If you really want a single template, try out the articles Shai has pointed out. Thx for the links by the way, did not know those articles!

Comment: @Shai what an awesome paper. Good work! I'll have a read while I'm at work :-)

Comment: @Shai ,

Hey i encountered an error in the matlab code for 
"Detecting and sketching the common"

the link for the image with error is 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fTeeazmL-Fb0NDTlZzQzdKNGM/edit?usp=sharing

Plz guide

Comment: @Harry have you ran `mexall` after downloading the code? there is some mex code needs to be compiled before you try out the code. Please **READ** the README file that comes with the code.

Comment: @Shai problem resolved thank you... indeed a great work and paper..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can train a SVM model (http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-svm.html) on the images you have with the matched images as positive samples and the unmatched images as negative samples. Finally you will get ONE template.